# arduino power supply protection

Tags: power-supply, arduino, voltage-regulator

Arduino mega documentation mentions that it can be powered up with a 7-9 volt power supply via a power jack (onboard).

Although, the Arduino board has its voltage regulator failure on the external power supply causing damage to the board. How to prevent this problem?

Should I use another voltage regulator with a combination of a fuse or something like a zener diode to protect against any voltage failure before damaging my Arduino board?

Comment: `failure on the external power supply causing damage to the board.` what kind of failure on the external power supply damages your Mega board?

Comment: I'm using a linear power supply with LM317 regulator Ic. burning LM317 in some cases makes a short circuit within input and output pin. in this case the output will be around 25~35 volt (I'm using a centered tap 24V transformator) @RohatKılıç